# Homestead / Homestead.yaml (Windows) no input file specified

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

I used to work with homestead on a mac machine, but since i don't have access to that mac machine anymore i'm back on my windows machine.

So today i installed homestead with no problems, ran vagrant up and got: No input file specified.

which is normal because i didn't set my homestead.yaml to the right folders. so this i where i started to ran into problems.

I have a .Projects folder in my user directory and there i have a laravel 5.4 installation called test

this is my homestead.yaml (only the folder's and site's section)

```
folders:
- map: ~/Projects
  to: /home/vagrant/Projects

sites:
- map: test.dev
  to: /home/vagrant/Projects/test/public
```

Still the same message and i realy don't know why i hope someone with homestead + windows can help me !

Comment: Is the ~/Projects directory available from under the virtual machine?

Comment: Is the folder in your user directory called ".Projects" or "Projects"? Your Homestead config indicates it's looking for "~/Projects", make sure that folder exists on your PC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve your site from `homestead ssh`.

`serve test.dev /home/vagrant/Projects/test/public`

then `sudo nginx restart`

You need to register your site from **homestead** first.